# landing on 1st div, scroll down to next div, and disable to scroll back to 1st div. how to achieve this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have saw something similar effect like this:
The user landed on first div which is the landing section, then the user scroll down to the next div which is where the website start.
And they can't scroll back to the first div/landing section anymore after scrolling down.
I have attached an image here to explain.

[image]

How can I do something like this? I remember I have seen it somewhere, but I can't recall back now.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Show the code on how you have tried this thing, no one is going to write the whole code

Comment: i just wonder the name of this function, not really want to spoon feed with code

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($jq) {
$jq(document).ready(function() {
  function FirstScrool() {
    var cScrollVal = $jq(document).scrollTop(),
      body = $jq("body"),
      header = $jq("#Landing"),
      hHeight = header.outerHeight(),
      hClass = "hide-landing";
    console.log("cScrollVal ==>" + cScrollVal)
    console.log("hHeight ==>" + hHeight)
    if (cScrollVal >= (hHeight / 2)) {
      if (!body.hasClass(hClass)) { body.addClass(hClass); }
    } 
  }
  $jq(window).scroll(function() {
    FirstScrool();
  });
});
})(jQuery)
```

Check the below link:
https://codepen.io/gopimx/pen/yLLjbGv

Comment: Hi, this is work. But the red box/Landing is hiding too fast, I have demo it here: - 
https://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/QWWrxad . Can it only hide after the Red box fully scroll up? and with some easing as well?